# How do I make an Excel VBA macro to delete columns with many different strings as headers?

Tags: string, excel, vba

So I'm importing a large spreadsheet with anywhere from 20 to 40 headers at the top and I'd like to automatically (and quickly) delete all the columns with specific headers.  I have a current code that works, but it loops through all the columns multiple times, each time looking for a different string.  I would like it to loop through once and delete any column that has any of the strings to delete.

Here's a fraction of my code to explain a little better:

```
Sub SetUpICTRP()

‘MsgBox “Excel will refresh when macro is complete”
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim lastColumn As Long

lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Cells(1, lastColumn))   

Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find("column", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireColumn.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find("Erroneous", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireColumn.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find("Unnecessary", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireColumn.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find("Not_", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireColumn.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So currently it will delete all the columns with headers that contain the phrase "column," "Erroneous," "Unnecessary", and "Not_". What I really need is for it to be able to find and delete columns like "column218", "columnadfe", "column099", "Not_needed", without running through a separate loop multiple times.  I think the solution lies somehow in creating an array of strings and then looping through each string for each column, but I'm rather new to VBA and can't seem to make that work. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through and find the words and use the `Union()` method to collate your headers into a single Range object, then use the `.EntireColumn` method to delete columns related to the non-contiguous cells.

---

```
Sub SO()

Dim findValue As Variant, findRange As Excel.Range, deleteRange As Excel.Range
Dim findAddress As String

For Each findValue In Array("column", "Erroneous", "Unnecessary", "Not_", _
    "Other1", "Other2", "Other3", "etc...")

    Set findRange = Rows(1).EntireRow.Find(what:=findValue, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)

    If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
        findAddress = findRange.Address
        Do
            If Not deleteRange Is Nothing Then
                Set deleteRange = Union(deleteRange, findRange)
            Else
                Set deleteRange = findRange
            End If

            Set findRange = Rows(1).EntireRow.FindNext(findRange)
        Loop Until findRange Is Nothing Or findRange.Address = findAddress

    Set findRange = Nothing
    End If

Next findValue

If deleteRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No columns were found for deletion!"
Else
    deleteRange.EntireColumn.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

or following your original setup you could use something like:

```
Sub SO()

Dim c As Range, findValue As Variant

For Each findValue In Array("column", "Erroneous", "Unnecessary", "Not_", _
    "Other1", "Other2", "Other3", "etc...")
    Do
        Set c = Rows(1).EntireRow.Find(findValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireColumn.Delete
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing

Next findValue

End Sub
```

Comment: That seems like exactly the type of solution I need, the only problem is that it's saying "Delete method of Range class failed" and highlights the "deleteRange.EntireColumn.Delete" row as the source of the error. Do you know why that might be happening?

Comment: Do you have any merged cells in your header row?

Comment: Nope, they're all separate

Comment: If it makes a difference, the columns that are being deleted are interspersed with columns that aren't being deleted so that the deleteRange might be something like (C:C,E:E,F:F,I:I). Can excel delete columns that aren't adjacent with one delete command?

Comment: Yes, Excel can delete non-contiguous columns for instance `Range("A1:C1, E1, H1:L1").EntireColumn.Delete` would delete columns A, B, C, E, H, I, J, K and L.

Comment: Try stepping through the code and making sure that it's finding the ranges and setting them correctly - if `deleteRange` is `Nothing` then it will error because there is nothing to delete.

Comment: In the first iteration "deleteRange" gets set to be "column". From what I see, it then tries to "deleteRange.EntireColumn.Delete", but since none of the columns are actually named just "column" but are "column1" "column2" "column3", it might be giving me this error.  It seems to be returning the name of the header as the range instead of the column number

Comment: `deleteRange` should be a range object, it shouldn't have a text value - are you using the code exactly as I posted it or have you adapted it? Try opening the locals window to see what is happening with the variables at run time

Comment: So I've been debugging and it seems as if the first time around it identifies the column "column1" and stores that as deleteRange.  The second iteration it then goes to the next findValue and begins searching for "Erroneous" even though there are still more columns named "column2" "column3" to delete. Additionally, when it sets deleteRange = Union(deleteRange, findRange), deleteRange never concatenates the two and ends up as deleteRange without the findRange portion.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Right, so you actually want it to find all occurrences of that word and add them to the range. Also check the address property of `deleteRange` after the `Union()` method - it will join the ranges, but they all become "deleteRange" there is no name change involved. I'll make an edit shortly.